# Set a flag in source table when record is inserted in target table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I would like to set a flag in source table, when a record is inserted a target table.

Example:
Source table:

```
Name company flag
AAA XXXX 0
BBB YYYY 0
```

Once the target table has data

```
ID name company

    1 AAA XXXX
```

Source table :

```
Name company flag
AAA XXXX 1
```

Basically, I want to check if ID has been generated in target table, If it is genereated then make flag 1 in source.
I can do this in sql or in execute sql task. anything is fine.

How can I do this?
any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You need an `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.flag = 1
FROM dbo.SourceTable A
INNER JOIN dbo.TargetTable B
    ON a.Name = B.Name
    AND A.company = B.company
WHERE A.flag = 0;
```

Comment: Probably inside a trigger.. Was writing a similar `UPDATE` query with similar `Where` clause ;) +1

Comment: @Prdp Yeah, if it needs to be "on-line" then an `AFTER INSERT` trigger on the target table would be the right way. Otherwise, just running this `UPDATE` at some fixed times would do